# Docker does not set the RAM via docker run command

Tags: docker, htop

The command that I run is

```
docker run --rm --cpuset-cpus="0-3" --memory="8g" -v ~/IdeaProjects:/sources --name dsetup -it harit/akka-dev-setup:1.0
```

When I do `htop` inside my container I see that it still uses `2g`
[image]

I am sure, I am wrong, but not sure where ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The **--memory** or **-m** parameter is used to set the limit, it is not used for allocation, From: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

> Memory reservation is a kind of memory soft limit that allows for greater sharing of memory. Under normal circumstances, containers can use as much of the memory as needed and are constrained only by the hard limits set with the -m/--memory option. When memory reservation is set, Docker detects memory contention or low memory and forces containers to restrict their consumption to a reservation limit.

The ram you are seeing in htop is from your docker host, to view the container RAM and CPU usage use: **docker stats**